# Product of independent continuous local martingales is local martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Revuz-Yor's book mentioned if $M$ and $N$ are independent continuous local martingales, then $MN$ is still local martingale. But I don't know how to prove it. Any help, thanks!

Comment: A (local) martingale with respect to which filtration?

Comment: @saz The book only said the independent means the natural fields generated by $M$ $N$ respectively are independent. I think $M$ $N$ are with respect to a same filtration wich is larger than the natural filtrations they generated respectively.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that you should *always* specify the filtration since the answer depends, in general, on the given filtration. The following statements are both correct:

> 1. Let $(X_t,\mathcal{F}_t^X)_{t \geq 0}$, $(Y_t,\mathcal{F}_t^Y)_{t \geq 0}$ be continuous local  martingales with respect to their natural filtration. Then $(X_t Y_t, \mathcal{F}_t^{X Y})_{t \geq 0}$ is a local martingale.
> 2. Let $(X_t,\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$, $(Y_t,\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be continuous local martingales. Then $(X_t Y_t, \mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a local martingale.

The continuity of the processes is crucial; the statements do not hold if the martingales are not continuous. For proofs see e.g. this (quite accessible) article by [Cherny](http://mech.math.msu.su/~cherny/pmt.pdf).